# Observable with pairwise not firing in test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, ts-jest, jasmine-marbles

Trying to test a method that is using pairwise.

Method:

```js
this.x$.pipe(pairwise()).subscribe((x) => {
      const [previous, current] = x;
      this.store.dispatch(actionThatIWantToFire({ appId: current }));
    });
```

For demonstration purposes. I'm aware that I don't need pairwise. Pretend that I do.

test:

```js
it(
    `should dispatch`,
    waitForAsync(() => {
      const dispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(store, 'dispatch');
      (component.x$ as Observable<any>) = cold('a---b|', {
        a: '123',
        b: '1234',
      });

      getTestScheduler().flush();
      expect(dispatchSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
       actionThatIWantToFire,
      );
    }),
  );
```

But the code within the subscription never gets called. Only way to call it is to remove the `pairwise`.
Any ideas?

Comment: pairwise doesn't emit a single value until the source emits a second value. If `this.x$` doesn't emit twice, then there will be no pairs. That's one possibility.

Comment: The marble is emitting 2 values. And pairwise will emit a single value. The `previous` will be `undefined`

Comment: What? The Marble? [(link: look here)](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/pairwise). Specifically: "pairwise emits on the second and subsequent emissions from the source Observable, but not on the first emission"

Comment: (component.x$ as Observable<any>) = cold('a---b|', {
        a: '123',
        b: '1234',
      });

Comment: Same thing happening to me. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: No. Never did. Tried for a bit then gave up.

Comment: When do you subscribe to `x$`? Is it during `OnInit` or in `constructor`. If it is before `OnInit`, then the reason is simple. If you replace the observable that you subscribed to with one you never subscribe to again, it will never fire... And the replaced original will not fire either...

Comment: It’s subscribed on init but the test does not detectChanges till after the simplified test above is written. 

There would be no way of knowing that by looking above.  Good idea but that was taking into account.

Answer (score -1):

From the RxJs Documentation :

> Keep in mind that pairwise will not emit an initial value until the observable emits at least two values. This behavior can lead to confusion, as there will be no output and no error, but the observable might not be functioning as intended or is waiting for more values.

I found a workaround using startwith before using pairwise :

```
this.x$.pipe(
  startWith(INITIAL_VALUE),
  pairwise()
).subscribe((x) => {
  const [previous, current] = x;
  this.store.dispatch(actionThatIWantToFire({ appId: current }));
});
```

Comment: This was asked a long time ago so I’m no longer needing an answer but this ^ is not it. The marble in the test is clearly emitting. 

And the startwith changes the functionality to a point where it’s unusable. 

So I’ll be downvoting this solution.